# Differentiating F(u, v) = f(x(u, v), y(u, v))

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, chain-rule

Let $f(x,y)$ be a given differentiable function.

Consider the function $F(u,v) = f( x(u,v), y(u,v) )$ where

$x = \frac{1}{2u^2} - v, y = v^2.$

Prove that

$u^3\frac{dF}{du} - \frac{dF}{dv} = -2\sqrt y\frac{df}{dy}$

I'm having difficulty differentiating this function. I think it uses the chain rule but I'm unsure of how to go about it. Any help is very much appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Something is wrong here. For example if $f(x,y)=y$ then $F(u,v)=v$ and then $u^3F_u-F_v=0-1=-1$, but $-2\sqrt{y}f_y=-2\sqrt{y}$.

Comment: @smcc Sorry I edited the question there, $y = v^2$

Comment: There is still a problem. If $f(x,y)=x+y$ and $y=v^2$ then $F(u,v)=\frac{1}{2u^2}$ and $u^3F_u-F_v=-1$ while $-2\sqrt{y}f_y=-2\sqrt{y}$.

Comment: @smcc this is quite embarrassing. Another edit made, I had swapped the $v$ and $v^2$... Checked the rest of the question and it's all correct now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By the chain rule,

$$F_u(u,v)=f_xx_u+f_yy_u$$

and

$$F_v(u,v)=f_xx_v+f_yy_v$$

Now, $x_u=-1/u^3$, $x_v=-1$, $y_u=0$ and $y_v=2v$. Therefore

$$F_u(u,v)=-\frac{f_x}{u^3}\quad \iff \quad f_x=-u^3F_u$$

and

$$F_v(u,v)=-f_x+2vf_y.$$

Substituting for $f_x$ in the second equation gives

$$F_v=u^3F_u+2vf_y\quad\iff\quad u^3F_u-F_v=-2vf_y$$

Since $v=\pm\sqrt{y}$, we get

$$u^3F_u-F_v=\pm2\sqrt{y}f_y.$$